# Spark 1.5.2: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Union;

Tags: apache-spark

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. Both of them have the following schema:

```
 |-- ts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- managers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- projects: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

`df1` is created from an avro file while `df2` from an equivalent parquet file. However, If I execute, `df1.unionAll(df2).show()`, I get the following error:

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Union;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:103)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into the same situation and it turns out to be not only the fields need to be the same but also you need to maintain the exact same ordering of the fields in both dataframe in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the order matters!

Comment: and the data type of the fields as well

Comment: @Even Cheng any clue how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963925/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-project

Answer (score 3):

This is old and there are already some answers lying around but I just faced this problem while trying to make a union of two dataframes like in...

```
//Join 2 dataframes
val df = left.unionAll(right)
```

As others have mentioned, order matters. So just select right columns in the same order than left dataframe columns

```
//Join 2 dataframes, but take columns in the same order    
val df = left.unionAll(right.select(left.columns.map(col):_*))
```

Comment: any clue how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963925/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-project

Answer (score 2):

I found the following PR on github

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11333.

That relates to `UDF` (user defined function) columns, which were not correctly handled during the union, and thus would cause the union to fail. The PR fixes it, but it hasn't made it to spark `1.6.2`, I haven't checked on `spark 2.x` yet.

If you're stuck on `1.6.x` there's a stupid work around, map the `DataFrame` to an `RDD` and back to a `DataFrame`

```
// for a DF with 2 columns (Long, Array[Long])
val simple = dfWithUDFColumn
  .map{ r => (r.getLong(0), r.getAs[Array[Long]](1))} // DF --> RDD[(Long, Array[Long])]
  .toDF("id", "tags") // RDD --> back to DF but now without UDF column

// dfOrigin has the same structure but no UDF columns
val joined = dfOrigin.unionAll(simple).dropDuplicates(Seq("id")).cache()
```

Comment: any clue how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963925/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-project