# Add a new key/value pair to a Spark MapType column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with a MapType field.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> fields = StructType([
...         StructField('timestamp',      TimestampType(), True),
...         StructField('other_field',    StringType(), True),
...         StructField('payload',        MapType(
...                                         keyType=StringType(),
...                                         valueType=StringType()),
...                                                     True),   ])
>>> import datetime
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([[datetime.datetime.now(), 'this should be in', {'akey': 'aValue'}]])
>>> df = rdd.toDF(fields)
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|           timestamp|      other_field|            payload|
+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|2018-01-10 12:56:...|this should be in|Map(akey -> aValue)|
+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to add the `other_field` as a key in the `payload` field.

I know I can use a udf:

```
>>> def _add_to_map(name, value, map_field):
...     map_field[name] = value
...     return map_field
...
>>> add_to_map = udf(_add_to_map, MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
>>> df.select(add_to_map(lit('other_field'), 'other_field', 'payload')).show(1, False)
+------------------------------------------------------+
|PythonUDF#_add_to_map(other_field,other_field,payload)|
+------------------------------------------------------+
|Map(other_field -> this should be in, akey -> aValue) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this *without* a `udf`?

Comment: I am worried about taking the performance hit from the row-wise python operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it without `udf` if you know the keys ahead of time. Use the `create_map` function. As to whether or not this is more performant, I don't know.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, create_map

df.select(
    create_map(
        lit('other_field'),
        col('other_field'),
        lit('akey'),
        col('payload')['akey']
    )
).show(n=1, truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|map(other_field, other_field, akey, payload['akey']) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Map(other_field -> this should be in, akey -> aValue)|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

## Update

Here is a way to do it without having to hardcode the dictionary keys. Unfortunately it involves one `collect()` operation.

#### Mockup some data

Firstly, let's modify your original dataframe to include one more key-value pair in the `MapType()` field.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, create_map
import datetime
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [
        [
            datetime.datetime.now(),
            'this should be in',
            {'akey': 'aValue', 'bkey': 'bValue'}
        ]
    ]
)
df = rdd.toDF(fields)
df.show(n=1, truncate=False)
```

Which creates the following:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|timestamp                 |other_field      |payload                            |
+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|2018-01-10 17:37:58.859603|this should be in|Map(bkey -> bValue, akey -> aValue)|
+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

#### Get the map's keys

Using `explode()` and `collect()`, you can get the keys as so:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

keys = [
    x['key'] for x in (df.select(explode("payload"))
                        .select("key")
                        .distinct()
                        .collect())
]
```

#### Create a new map with all of the fields

Now use `create_map` as above, but use the information from `keys` to create the key-value pairs dynamically. I used `reduce(add, ...)` because `create_map` expects the inputs to be key-value pairs in order- I couldn't think of another way to flatten the list.

```
from operator import add
df.select(
    create_map
    (
        *([lit('other_field'), col('other_field')] + reduce(add, [[lit(k), col('payload').getItem(k)] for k in keys]))
    )
).show(n=1, truncate=False)
```

#### Final result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|map(other_field, other_field, akey, payload['akey'], bkey, payload['bkey'])|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Map(other_field -> this should be in, akey -> aValue, bkey -> bValue)      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## References

1. [pyspark: Create MapType Column from existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288622/pyspark-create-maptype-column-from-existing-columns)
2. [PySpark converting a column of type 'map' to multiple columns in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869134/pyspark-converting-a-column-of-type-map-to-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: The keys don't change very often in my case, so precomputing the keys might give me a performance gain, I will try it out. Thanks @pault

Comment: Happy to help. Please do share the performance results. I'm curious to see how the various methods stack up against each other.

Comment: No noticeable performance difference. However, this is still useful for folk on spark <1.6 because of union all. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650568/spark-1-5-2-org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-union

Comment: But are these methods faster than `udf`? Or did you mean that these methods had no performance difference than `udf`?

Comment: I would have to put together a more rigorous test to see, I will get back to you :)

Comment: @pault, great explanation. I would like to apply what you mention here in my question. Can you take a look at it as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070186/pyspark-mapping-values-from-different-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment109790263_62070186

Answer (score 5):

Using [map_concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_concat) & [create_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) (pyspark 2.4+):

```
(
    df.withColumn(
        "new_map",
        F.map_concat(
            "old_map",
            F.create_map(F.lit("key"), F.lit("val"))
        )
    )
)
```

You can add multiple keys at once thanks to F.create_map, but F.map_concat won't replace old keys.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reaches this question, but looking the solution for **Scala**:

```
df.withColumn("payload", map_concat(col("payload"), map(lit("other_field"), col("other_field"))))
```