# How to add new key/value to the existing column of MapType(StringType(), StringType())?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a new key/value to the existing column of MapType(StringType(), StringType()).
I'd like to add 'age' to the col_1.

What functions should I use to complete the task?

`df.show()`

| id | col_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {name-> James} |
| 2 | {name-> Charlie} |

to

| id | col_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {name-> James, age-> 20} |
| 2 | {name-> Charlie, age-> 29} |

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71395830/9477843)

Answer (score 0):

Create a map for the `age` column and use `map_concat` to merge the two maps.

```
# input data
data_sdf.show()

# +---+-----------------+---+
# | id|            col_1|age|
# +---+-----------------+---+
# |  1|  {name -> James}| 20|
# |  2|{name -> Charlie}| 29|
# +---+-----------------+---+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('col_1_updated',
               func.map_concat('col_1', func.create_map(func.lit('age'), func.col('age')))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----------------+---+----------------------------+
# |id |col_1            |age|col_1_updated               |
# +---+-----------------+---+----------------------------+
# |1  |{name -> James}  |20 |{name -> James, age -> 20}  |
# |2  |{name -> Charlie}|29 |{name -> Charlie, age -> 29}|
# +---+-----------------+---+----------------------------+
```

If there are multiple columns and you want to create the map dynamically, you can use `reduce` to create the input to the `create_map`.

```
cols_to_map = ['age', 'gender', 'email']
input_to_create_map = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [[func.lit(k), func.col(k)] for k in cols_to_map])

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('col_1_updated',
               func.map_concat('col_1', 
                               func.create_map(*input_to_create_map)
                               )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----------------+---+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |id |col_1            |age|gender|email      |col_1_updated                                                  |
# +---+-----------------+---+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |{name -> James}  |20 |M     |abc@xyz.com|{name -> James, age -> 20, gender -> M, email -> abc@xyz.com}  |
# |2  |{name -> Charlie}|29 |M     |foo@bar.com|{name -> Charlie, age -> 29, gender -> M, email -> foo@bar.com}|
# +---+-----------------+---+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```